Duplicate array and using both are sorted rather than just the duplicate
When duplicating an array and using sort(), why do both arrays get sorted?
For example:


c = [2,4,9,1,10];
b = c;
b.sort();
console.log(b+" "+c)



I was expecting the array (c) to remain as [2,4, 9, 1, 10] instead it returns the same as b using sort() with both returning [1, 10, 2, 4, 9]

b = c does not duplicate an array. You just gave the array a second name by which to call it. As per Márius Rak's answer, use b = c.toSorted() to get an actual sorted copy.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value

And on a debugging note: don't use console.log(b+" "+c). You're not working with strings, just log your variables: console.log({b, c}), so you can actually inspect the entire thing instead of only being able to make guesses based on string coercion.

toSorted() works perfectly.

This question is similar to: Fastest way to duplicate an array in JavaScript - slice vs. 'for' loop. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, sort() changes array "in place" as is stated in docs. You need to make a copy by [...c] or you can use toSorted()

The toSorted is an excellent call-out: most people never reread the list of Array functions and have no idea that function even exists (for those who work with JS a lot and don't know about it: it got added in 2023)

The actual Concept here is of Reference.
When you are assigning b = c, it points b to the same reference as of c, so when you sort b, it also sorts c because both pointed at the same reference.
Possible Sol: -

Use Spread Operator(ES6 Syntax) -

let b = [...c];  // 'b' is a new array with the same elements as 'c'
b.sort();
console.log(b);  // Output: [1, 2, 4, 9, 10]
console.log(c);  // Output: [2, 4, 9, 1, 10]


Use a function toSorted() -

let b = c.toSorted();  // it returns the sorted array(without affecting c)
console.log(b);  // Output: [1, 2, 4, 9, 10]
console.log(c);  // Output: [2, 4, 9, 1, 10]


So in this case you are modifying the array in place, pointing to same memory location, you need to create a copy of c array by using a method called array destructuring/sperad operator. i.e b=[...c] and now you can perform sort operation on array b which does not affect array c

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
